# Power BI Report to Display A SharePoint List Item's Attributes

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, powerbi

I created a Power BI report to display list items from a SharePoint List.  Can someone lead me in the right direction as to how to display the item details in another report page, or even in the same page.  Here is my list data, I want to click an item and display the column data for that item.  Thanks in advance for your help
[image]

Answer (score 1):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-sharepoint-online-list

And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-quick-create-sharepoint-list

And: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/quickly-create-reports-from-sharepoint-lists/

To get started:

- Open Power BI and in the Home tab, select `Get data > More > Online Services`, and then connect the List.
- Put the URL of the site containing the list in the Site URL field of the dialog box.
- On the left side select the SharePoint list, then select Load, this will load it in a report
- On the list select `Integrate > Power BI > Visualize the list`. This will generate a report showing the data.
- Finally you can publish the report to the list.

Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZO3x2NF8Ak

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response, I created the report that displays the list items, like a view in SharePoint.  What I want is to have a view item button, link, whatever, to display a selected list item's details.  I wasn't very clear of that in my question.

Comment: Check this and let me know if this is what youre looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-sharepoint-online-list